# HighCharts : xAxis Date format issue

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

When I set Date format for `XAxis`. It's not working
Below is my code :

```
let options = HIOptions()

xAxis.categories = ["2022-01-17T00:00:00","2022-01-18T00:00:00","2022-01-19T00:00:00","2022-01-20T00:00:00","2022-01-21T00:00:00"]

xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats = HIDateTimeLabelFormats() 

xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.month = HIMonth()

xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.month.main = "%e. %b"

options.xAxis = [xAxis]
```

It display original date from array only which I have set in `xAxis.categories`

Comment: instead of the original date what do you need to show?

Comment: i want to display "MM.DD" like "01.17"

Comment: Have you tried to use datatime xAxis type? Just like it is done in this official demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

Comment: Yes i have set xAxis.type = "datetime"

Comment: And how your data structure looks like?